# Mongodb aggregation, Use value from a variable in the expression of $group _id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I am trying to groups documents by two fields, `field1` and `field2`.

```
myCollection.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      group1: "$field1",
      group2: "$field2"
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
}])
```

Which works fine producing the expected results.

But I want to re run the above in a loop, each run will have different `$field2`, so the following is failing, how can I it be done?  Thanks

```js
const field3 = 'someValue';  // <<--- will change in every loop run ---

myCollection.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      group1: "$field1",
      group2: "$$field3"  //<<---------------- 
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
}])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work for you

```
var field3  = 'someValue';
myCollection.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      group1: "$field1",
      group2: "$" + field3,
    },
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
}])
```